# Populate `NA` with character value for a specific time span in grouped data frame

Tags: r, dplyr

In this type of data, where `Story` is a grouping variable:

```
df <- data.frame(
  id = 1:20,
  Story = c(rep("x",10), rep("y",10)),
  Climax = c(NA,NA,"climax1","climax1", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA,
             NA,NA,"climax2","climax2", "climax2", NA, NA, NA, NA, NA),
  Endtime_eda = c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.5,0.6,0.7,0.8,0.9,1.0,
                  0.11,0.22,0.33,0.44,0.55,0.66,0.77,0.88,0.99,1.11)
)
```

I need to populate the `NA` values in `Climax` with the `Story`-specific `Climax` value further down but only as far as, say, 0.2 seconds on the `Endtime_eda` timeline for each `Story` and then filter the data frame for rows with positive `Climax` annotation. I've come up with this code, which does work for the toy data in `df`:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>%
  group_by(Story) %>%
  mutate(max = max(Endtime_eda[!is.na(Climax)])) %>%
  filter(Endtime_eda < max + 0.2) %>%
  fill(Climax, .direction = "down") %>%
  filter(!is.na(Climax))
# A tibble: 8 × 5
# Groups:   Story [2]
     id Story Climax  Endtime_eda   max
  <int> <chr> <chr>         <dbl> <dbl>
1     3 x     climax1        0.3   0.4 
2     4 x     climax1        0.4   0.4 
3     5 x     climax1        0.5   0.4 
4     6 x     climax1        0.6   0.4 
5    13 y     climax2        0.33  0.55
6    14 y     climax2        0.44  0.55
7    15 y     climax2        0.55  0.55
8    16 y     climax2        0.66  0.55
```

But for the actual data set I get Warnings:

```
Warning in View :
  NAs introduced by coercion
Warning in View :
  no non-missing arguments to max; returning -Inf
```

and the `max` values do not seem to be fully correct. What's the issue in the code? How could it be improved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Difficult to help without having data to reproduce the issue.

My guess is that the warnings are coming from instances where all the values of `Climax` are `NA` for a particular `Story` so there is no `Endtime_eda` value from which `max` can be taken.

You may try out this code which I think will give you a better idea of next steps to be taken.

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

df %>%
  group_by(Story) %>%
  mutate(max = if(all(is.na(Climax))) NA else 
                  max(Endtime_eda[!is.na(Climax)])) %>%
  filter(Endtime_eda < max + 0.2 | is.na(max)) %>%
  fill(Climax, .direction = "down")
```

There are 3 things which I have changed here -

1. If all the values of `Climax` is `NA` then return `NA` as `max` value.
2. `filter` by default drops `NA` values so added `| is.na(max)` to keep these rows.
3. Removed the last `filter(!is.na(Climax))` for you to check the output and then add it if it makes sense for your data.

Comment: Ah, now it works: forgot to convert `Endtime_eda` to numeric!